# Chrome Extension OAuth Provider

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm planning a browser extension (initially Chrome, but I'm also interested in answers relating to other browsers) which collects data about the user. I'd like to allow website developers to access this data  when the user browses to their website, but only if the user allows it. To achieve this, I think I basically want to implement an OAuth provider within the chrome extension.

Now, my experience with OAuth is limited to that of a user. I've used things like Passport to implement it before, but my understanding of how it all fits together is limited. Read: I think I understand it, but I'm probably wrong. I'm hoping that the air gap between web-pages and extensions is sufficient that the data will be secure if I don't provide explicit API access, but perhaps I'm not considering something enough.

My broad plan is something like this:

- User visits page
- Injected Content Script detects that the page wants access to the user's data
- Content Script triggers popup window to obtain user's permission
- If the user consents, listen to messages passed from the page, and respond appropriately (i.e. allow access to the API).

Does this sound sensible? Have you come across any other applications which do something like this, and are there any guides for a standard implementation?

*Clarification edit after some confusion*: My extension has unique data. I want arbitrary website developers to be able to use the extension's data in their own webpages, but only if the user approves. The injected script only serves as a bridge between the webpage and my extension.

Comment: does not seem oauth providers have anything to do. explain in detail why am oauth provider.

Comment: If we consider the three actors in an OAuth transaction: the user, the consumer, and the service provider. In my situation, the user is the user; the consumer is the web page; and the service provider would be my chrome extension. The difference with "traditional" OAuth is that I'm not using redirects, but I'm using a popup instead. Is this too far removed to be relevant?

Comment: this is not what oauth is for. you are writting all the code, the website is not negotiating access so no need for oauth here. if you were to make a standard api for website themselves (not you injecting code on them) then maybe use oauth.

Comment: I'm not writing the website - my injected content script is just giving the website access to the extension's API. Otherwise there would be no way for the webpage to communicate with the extension.

Comment: you are injecting the code into the webpage. they (the website developers) are not directly using it.

Comment: Perhaps you could (as an answer) explain in more detail how to achieve what I want? To confirm: any webpage can request access to the data provided by my extension, but only those which the user "approves" will receive the data.

Comment: but you want website developers to use your api, or you plan to do it from the extension?

Comment: I want website developers to use my API. Like I mentioned earlier - the injected script only serves as a bridge between the webpage and my extension.

Comment: aha thats key info. i thought you wanted for example to autocomplete a facebook login or other data your injected script automatically recognizes it could provide (without the website itself asking for it). in that case oauth makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87294/discussion-between-hephistocles-and-zig-mandel).